# Is best Big O Time efficiency always the same as best Space efficiency for recursive solutions?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, performance

If a recursive solution ends up calling itself consecutively for say, ~N times, before going back up a level, the space efficiency is O(N) at best, because each of the N calls uses up a certain amount of stack space.

Does this also imply the time efficiency is also O(N) at best, because the code inside the recursive function is similar to an inner loop code that gets run ~N times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Ben's answer there is also the case of "[tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)" where the current stack frame is removed and replaced by the callee's stack frame, but only when the caller's last action is to return the result of a callee. This can result in O(n) time functions having O(1) space when implemented in an entirely functional language.

Comment: Not only in functional languages and not only tail-recursive(ly written) functions. `unsigned long factorial(unsigned long n) { if (n == 0) return 1; return n*factorial(n-1); }` gets rewritten to a loop by gcc with `-O3`.

Answer (score 1):

No, but your observation has some truth in it - basically if you know that any algorithm (recursive or otherwise, since we don't distinguish the two; and there isn't anything really that could distinguish them, it's more a matter of style) for a given problem has space complexity at least `f(n)`, it must have time complexity at least `f(n)`, too.

Comment: This is inaccurate. An array can be used as set for example, and to be [initialized in O(1)](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time/). Assuming *allocating* memory is `O(1)` (which is not true for turing machines, but might be for some architectures) - this gives a possibility for algorithms with worse space complexity then time complexity

Comment: Note: The above comment is talking about *algorithms*. When talking about *problems* - it is a different story, since [DTIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTIME) <= [DSPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE)

Answer (score 0):

No, since each step of the recursive algorithm can take longer than O(1). If each step take O(n) then the total time complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: hi sorry i've edited my title to make it less misleading. i am interested in the best case big O, not whether they are always the same. sorry about that!

Comment: by best, i mean the lower limit of the time efficiency is the same as the lower limit of the space efficiency. example: if the space complexity is O(N), the time efficiency cannot be better than O(N).